# PHP How can I block direct URL files access

Tags: .htaccess, access-control

I am currently creating a project written in PHP, and there are a lot of files such as classes,procedures etc , that I prefer no one can access directly from URL.
I've thought about using .htaccess settings of the form :

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

I'd like to know if such settings would solve the problem , and I'd also like to know if there are another methods that I can use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for requires a so called "router" and rule that redirects all requests to one index as so to say "entrance" file.

Then you have to split the route in its several parts, build a logic and compare it with  a list of valid routes maybe stored in a routes file.

THis behaviour is very often paired with PHP frameworks using the MVC pattern.

You should google for "php route mvc" and you will find tutorials how to build those.

However a good start is to redirect all your requests to one specific file as described above.

You can use htaccess and it would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

This will call your front index.php file for every url, regardless if it points to an existing file or not.

Your index file should then contain a logic to extract your URL using servers vars such as $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] and analyze it and then internally redirect or better include the content you want to be displayed by this url.

Answer (score 2):

Probably best to move them out of the public root for your webserver, and instead reference them using a specialized loader class within the public (and just include from ../ etc)

It is not a wise move to store sensitive controllers and files within the web root.

Answer (score 1):

You can block access to certain files using .htaccess

```
<Files ~ "\.(ext)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

hope it works

I am afraid that by blocking direct access to files may cause unexpected results.

Comment: Basically this is fine yeah but the webserver wont decide if you are trying to include the file with an external url or if someone entered the page manually so this can make you trouble...

Answer (score 1):

The best way for me is either .htaccess as you said or using FileZilla, for example. You can change permission access to files/folders.

Or you can set a `$_SESSION['access']` just for you.

Don't forget to notify that you don't want those files to be annexed via robots.txt

```
Disallow: /your_folder/
Disallow: /your_file
```